# How to convert a seems like NV21 rtsp stream to normal YUV420 rtmp stream?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, yuv

I tried to push a live stream from H264 Encode Box(Based on Hi3516) 
to Bilibili using ffmpeg command line tool, but got a totally green picture.(It is all right when I push it to my local rtmp server.)

After searching, i got that the problem may lies in the U and V in YUV420, or NV12 and NV21.The remote server identifies error.

I previously use 
`-vcodec copy`
After change to 
`-vcodec h264`
Everything go well. But cost CPU to much. Emm Re-encoder? I don't need this.

So how can I convert only pixel format locally before push steam , or just tell the server my pixel format as to get a color correct picture?

Comment: Ah it's not totally green but looks green...Very green

Comment: Olla m8, you need to modify your question such it includes more information. Rightnow nobody is able to reproduce what you see. Perhaps include certain settings and some code references you use where you past the essentials? You also need to indicate what platform you are using... in short... elaborate a little more so we can help you out. Also try to paste in the picture you should see and what you get.

Comment: How did you configure the local rtmp server? What are ffmpeg parameters? How does ffmpeg classify the Encode Box video?

Comment: @AlexCohn Local server I use https://github.com/ossrs/srs and nginx-rtmp both ok. FFmpeg : `ffmpeg -i rtsp://URL -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://URL`

Comment: The question was, what color format and encoding  you see for incoming video

Comment: @AlexCohn ffmpeg shows : H.264(Baseline) YUV420P(progressive)

Comment: So, what made you think NV21 may be involved in this problem? See https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-troubleshoot-problematic-or-failed-rtsp-streams-between-ip-cameras-and-wowza-streaming-cloud - there may be other incompatibilities between the camera and the media server!

Comment: @AlexCohn cause someone in the internet also use Hi35xx , when they convert YUV to RGB they said like "swap the order of U and V" , so I think may be the difference of NV12 and NV21(different order of U V)

Comment: Swapping **U** and **V** (it's more accurate to say **Cr** and **Cb**) cannot produce greenish output. Loosing **CrCb** – can. You get green if instead of YUV you feed Y and enough zeros. At any rate, such swap cannot happen in the case of H.264 stream. But if your ffmpeg transcoder does not know the correct image size, this could result in something similar to what you see.

Comment: @AlexCohn Got it! What does "image size" refer to? Resolution?

Comment: yes, resolution, as described in https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-troubleshoot-problematic-or-failed-rtsp-streams-between-ip-cameras-and-wowza-streaming-cloud I included earlier

Comment: See https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/19127/capture-rtsp-stream-from-ip-camera-ffmpeg - the log shows that ffmpeg cannot find the image size from **rtsp:** stream.